# Mantener la conexión a una base de datos en varias paginas web

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente estoy diseñando un sitio web. En la primera pagina, hago una conexión a la base de datos que esta en SQL SERVER para validar si el usuario y la contraseña son validos. En este punto ya el logrado la conexión a la base de datos. Si el usuario y la contraseña son correctos, me lleva a otra pagina donde ingreso dos datos que serán necesarios para hacer otra consulta a la base de datos. Yo asumía que como ya había echo una conexión a la base de datos en la pagina inicial, el resto de paginas automáticamente también tendrían la conexión, pero no fue así ya que me salió este error en pantalla.

Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/analistaflota/conexion_sql_server.php on line 11

A continuación presento el código en cuya linea 11 esta la variable $stml.

```
?php
                //esta variable representa la consulta en la base de datos
                $año=$_POST['año'];
                $semana=$_POST['semana'];
                //luego de tener las variables ingresadas por medio de un formulario web, se las asigno a la consulta
                $sql_query="SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnTbCtmEstado]($año,$semana)";
                //esta es la funcion que me permite hacer la consulta y tenerla disponible
                $stml=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql_query);
?>
```

En la primera pagina yo había creado $con y había logrado la conexión para la validación de usuario y contraseña, pero al invocarla nuevamente en esta otra pagina, veo que ya no me funciona.

Estaré atento a recomendaciones y sugerencias que me puedan brindar, pues mi deseo es hacer la conexión a la base de datos una sola vez y poder utilizar dicha conexión en varias paginas web y una vez se cierre el sitio web, se efectué la desconexión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En PHP (y en general, en todo lo que sean scripts sobre Apache), cada vez que se recibe una petición HTTP que apunta a un script lo que hace Apache es lanzar un proceso independiente que ejecuta el script.

Al terminar el proceso de procesar la petición, todos los recursos que había generado el proceso se liberan, eso lo hace el sistema operativo.

Además, el nombre de las variables es algo muy "local" y que se procesa al compilar/interpretar el script. Incluso en sistemas que se ejecutan en un solo proceso (p.ej. un Tomcat con Java), cada nombre de variable tiene un ámbito en el que es válida y fuera de ese ámbito es totalmente desconocida.

Así que las variables que definas en una petición no estarán disponibles en otra petición.

Una cuestión con las BD es que abrir una conexión es bastante lento, así que normalmente hay mecanismos para que, en vez de abrir una petición desde cero, se mantnega un grupo de conexiones a BD abiertas y solicites una de estas en vez de crearla nueva. Pero aún con esto<sup>1</sup>, deberás definir la variable y solicitar una conexión para poder usarla en tu script.

<sup>1</sup>Para entendernos, esto solo afecta al rendimiento (para evitar abrir y cerrar continuamente conexiones a BD) y solo cambia cómo obtienes la conexión. Si estás empezando y es para hacer pruebas, simplemente crea una nueva conexión cada vez.

Comment: Gracias SJuan76 por la respuesta